# Extract JSON as String from jsp

Tags: java, json, jsoup

I am working on the parsing a website view-source:https://massive.ucsd.edu/ProteoSAFe/datasets.jsp. I want to parse the .jsp and extract the JSOn object from the same.

I am using Jsoup to extract the data

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://massive.ucsd.edu/ProteoSAFe/datasets.jsp").maxBodySize(0).get();`

Then using Java pattern to extract Json as string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "dataset","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "datasetNum","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "title","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "user","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "site","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "flowname","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "createdMillis","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "created","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "fileCount","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "fileSizeKB","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "psms","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "peptides","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "variants","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "proteins","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "species","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "instrument","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "modification","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "pi","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "complete","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "status","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "private","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "hash","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "px","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "task","\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", "id"));

Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html());
```

While doing so I am getting error. Last line is not getting parsed correctly.
It cuts in the end so I get

'A JSONObject text must end with '}' at character 577' error.

Can anyone suggest me better way to parse this page to get data.

Comment: Please use an actual JSON parser

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you please suggest any examples..To parse JSON I need to extract it first from the javascript script tag..Pattern is just doing that but getting error at the end.

Comment: I don't know where your error exists. You have no code shown that creates a `new JSONObject` or extracting anything from the `Matcher`. Please [edit] with a [mcve] of the problem. The error is self-explanatory, though. I'm not sure why you are trying to extract individual values from the JSON rather than the entire JSON string from `{` to `}`

Answer (score 1):

While it seems like a bad idea to parse any HTML with regex.

This works for me `Pattern.compile("(?s)var datasets = (\\[.*?\\]);")`

(Tested via Python, since that's all I have available).

And that returns a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Is there any way to extract out JSON out of HTML.

Comment: That's exactly what this does. It returns a string, that you pass to your JSON library of choice

Comment: Yeah I was able to do that.. but u said  bad idea to parse any HTML with regex.what is the other alternative?

Comment: You use JSoup to get the script tag... At that point, you are parsing Javascript, not HTML